# How do I create a Quarantine directory from which programs cannot execute?

Tags: directory, malware, antivirus, clamav

I have recently installed `clamav`, and I think I'd like to use the "move infected files option" to move any infected files it finds to my quarantine directory (`/virusScan/quarantine`, and yes, I own it) in case I miss some. However, I don't want to risk a virus *noticing* that it's been moved and activating. How can I modify the quarantine directory such that any program moved there cannot execute?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that by giving the `/virusScan/quarantine` directory different permissions.

```
sudo chmod 664 /virusScan/quarantine
```

This way you can read and write to the directory but not execute something from it, the group has as well the same permissions to read and write but not execute and others only can read.

Comment: Thank you for responding in _**4** minutes!_ Unfortunately, this did not work. The only way I could move anything into the directory was as root, and I do not want to run `clamav` as root.

Comment: No problem, you're very welcome on Ask Ubuntu, if my answer helped you you can accept it by clicking the check-mark beside it.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to finish editing that before you saw it. I accidentally pressed enter.

Comment: Then create a special group and user for `clamav` and make sure you add your own user to the group. Because `clamav` daemon runs annyways as root unless you change that.

Comment: How can I run `clamav` as that user?

Comment: You my have a look at their documentation [here](https://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav), and other places to look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV) and [here](https://qmail.jms1.net/clamav/daemontools.shtml)